# Saying there are 0 arguments when I have 2? Trying to open a CSV file to write into

Tags: ruby, file, csv, dir

I'm trying to read from a CSV file and codify people into groups using an equation.  I append the name of their group they fall into to the end of the array that their row creates.  Then I write it to a new file so I don't overwrite the original file in case something goes wrong.

Also, it loops through the directory and does this for multiple csv files.

However, when I try to open the new file to write into, it's saying this:

```
Segmenter.rb:12:in `open': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
        from Segmenter.rb:12:in `foreach'
        from Segmenter.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

Here is the script with the coefficients removed. All the x's in the coefficients array are numbers in my script.

```
require 'csv'

coefficients = [ 
[x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, "Utilitarians"],
[x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, "Hometown School/Social"],
[x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, "State Pride"],
[x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, "Hard-Wired Advocates"],
[x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, "Game Hunters"]
]

Dir.foreach do |current_file|

    data_set = CSV.read(current_file)

    data_set.array.each do |row|
        segment_value = 0
        segment_name = ""
        coefficients.each do |segment|
            if (segment[0] *  row[1] + segment[1]*row[2] + segment[2]*row[3] + segment[3]*row[4] + segment[4]*row[5] + segment[5]*row[6] + segment[6]*row[7] + segment[7]*row[8]) > segment_value
                segment_value = segment[0] *  row[1] + segment[1]*row[2] + segment[2]*row[3] + segment[3]*row[4] + segment[4]*row[5] + segment[5]*row[6] + segment[6]*row[7] + segment[7]*row[8]
                segment_name = segment[8]
            end
        row << segment_name
    end

    CSV.open("#{current_file.basename} SEGMENTED.csv", "w") do |writer|
        data_set.array.each do |data|
            writer << data
        end
    end

    end 

end
```

Comment: stupid question, but have you saved your code after changes? It says that the error is on line 12, but your open method is not even near it

Comment: Yeah. Its somehow rolling it in with the Dir.foreach call.  Anyway, that foreach call is on line 11 I think. I took out an unnecessary require after copying in the error. Then I copied in the actual script. Miniscule change that shouldnt matter.

Comment: Also no harm in asking. I called cat Segmenter.rb to make sure that wasnt the problem. Haha.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It wont let me open a csv file to write into. I don't understand why, and its also saying there are 0 arguments, and I supplied the filename and open type, so you would think there are two arguments.

Comment: If you’ve solved your problem, you should either post your answer below, which you can accept after 48 hours, or, if you think your question/answer are of no relevance to future visitors, you can delete your question entirely. You should *not* simply edit your question with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with `Dir.foreach`, not `CSV.open`.

You need to supply a directory to foreach as an argument. That's why you are getting the missing argument error.

Try:

`Dir.foreach('/path/to_my/directory') do |current_file|`

I think the `open` that is referenced in the error message is when `Dir` is trying to find the directory to open in order to get the file list for `foreach`.